# SAPUI5 - Can the Datepicker be configured

Tags: sapui5

Can the SAPUI5 Datepicker be configured to show only Sundays after a particular date (5 weeks from today) ?

Comment: It's hard to imagine a calendar displaying only Sundays. Maybe I misunderstood your question. Could you attach some screenshots / mockups of how such a calendar would look like? Did you mean *disable* the dates except of Sundays?

Answer (score -1):

```
<DatePicker id="DateOfBirth" change="handleChange"
                        class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom" width="78%" valueFormat="yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00"
                        displayFormat="MM.dd.yyyy" />
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question :(